# Adding inside function

Tags: ruby

I have some code that won't add two numbers. What have I done wrong?

```
class Add
  @@starting_value = 5

  def self.Adding
      puts "How much do you want to add? "
      user_choice = gets.to_i
      user_choice + @@starting_value
      puts "new value is" 
      puts @@starting_value
  end
end
```

Comment: Because you've created `Adding` as a class method (not an instance method), you need to invoke it with `Add.Adding`. Is that what you're doing? If so, it works fine.  You should use all lower case letters, with optional underscrores (e.g., `add_this`) for the names of variables and methods.

Comment: Method names should be lowercase, so use `self.adding` if you want a class method. But, "adding" isn't a good name because a method should really be a verb, an action, so use "add", but then the class name should be an item or thing, like Integer, not a verb. It gets tough doesn't it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
user_choice + @@starting_value
```

That adds the two values and then throws out the answer. You need to store the answer in a variable:

```
@@starting_value = user_choice + @@starting_value
```

Ruby has a special shortcut for this

```
@@starting_value += user_choice
```

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend reading the [Pickaxe book](https://pragprog.com/book/ruby/programming-ruby).  I assume you already have a Ruby implementation installed on your computer.

Create a file called, say, `add.rb`.  I would try to keep things as simple as possible:

```
class Add
    @amount = 5

    def self.add
        puts "How much do you want to add?"
        puts "New value is #{@amount + gets.to_i}"
    end
end

Add.add # add is a class method
```

Then run it with `ruby app.rb`.  The output should be something like:

```
How much do you want to add? 
100
New value is 105
```

Comment: Actually "The Pickaxe book" is a nickname for "Programming Ruby (2nd edition): The Pragmatic Programmers' Guide".

Comment: I thought that was obvious after clicking the link @theTinMan. You can edit if you like.